# UICollectionViewCell Selecting multiple cells swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to make an app to select multiple Cells, so let's assume we have 9 cells Indexed from 0 to 8.

Here is what i was trying to do...

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

   if cell?.selected == true {
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
   }

}
```

And Deselect Func()

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        
       var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
```

It's simple enough if a user selects a cell -> orange if deselects a cell -> clearColor 'white'
So yea this code is working except

If a user selects cell 0, it also change the color of cell 6, "keep in mind cell 6 is not selected it just change it's appearance". Same for Cell 1 if it selected cell 7 changes and so on, also if i deselect either cell 0 or cell 6 both Changes.

So i've tried `cell?.selected == true`, `UICollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` both properties did not work for me.

am i doing something Wrong ?
is it an issue related to Cell Reuse ? if so could you explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
         var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
         if cell?.selected == true {
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
         }
          else 
             cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Also make a custom cell for UICollectionViewCell. Also change in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function :

```
if cell?.selected == true 
      cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    else 
       cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: Tested your code, same behavior :(, clicking on a cell change the appearance of another cell

Answer (score 5):

First set `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection`

then for exemple to change border on click :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!

    selectedCell.layer.borderWidth = 2

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let unselectedCell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!

    unselectedCell.layer.borderWidth = 0
}
```

Comment: Also need to use this to avoid repetition.

override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {

            // logic
        }
    }