# Tap gesture on UICollectionView Cell using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-ui-automation

I am performing UI Automation in XCode using **Swift**

I would like to perform Tap gesture on UICollectionView with multiple Cells using **Swift**

As my Cells keeps on updating everyday. Is there anyway I can perform Tap gesture on anyone of the cell.

Comment: Try yourCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107856/uicollectionviewcell-selecting-multiple-cells-swift

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.tables.cells.forEach { $0.tap() }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tap on the first cell of the collectionView, assuming there is only one collection view in the current screen

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.collectionViews.element(boundBy:0).cells.element(boundBy:0).tap()
```

If there are multiple collectionView, find the collection View of current interest using 'po app.collectionViews.count', then find the index of the required collectionView. Say if it is at index 'n'. Then

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.collectionViews.element(boundBy:n).cells.element(boundBy:0).tap()
```

If you want to tap on any cell at random, within the collection view. then you can try this

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let randomCell = arc4random() % app.collectionViews.element(boundBy:n).cells.count
app.collectionViews.element(boundBy:n).cells.element(boundBy:randomCell).tap()
```